# Does using many small tables in Cassandra lower the free disk space requirements?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, consistent-hashing

Presently, we have tables which are over 100 gigabytes each. It was communicated to me that if we had many small tables this would be easier to handle. The idea being that Cassandra requires an amount of free space approximately equal to the table size when performing compression and compaction. If smaller tables are used, then the percentage of free space required on each node is smaller when these tasks are run.

If all my access is by key only in the large tables, it would not be difficult to put some consistent hashing logic in front of my database access code to determine which table contains what key.

Is there any advantage in Cassandra to using many small tables in software? Can the same advantages be achieved by changing the configuration of the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in principle, you could lower your free disk requirements by splitting your data into multiple tables or keyspaces.

A better option might be to use an alternative [compaction strategy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/planning/planningHardware.html#planPlanningHardware__disk). The default, **Sized Tiered** (STCS), requires reserving up to 50% free disk space.  Read heavy workloads may be able to use **Level Tiered** (LTCS) which needs only 10% free disk space and time series data can use **Date Tiered** (DTCS) where free disk space requirements are tuneable by setting the window size.

Before using either LTCS or DTCS, you **must** ensure that your workload fits the compaction strategy.  Both of these have severe performance risks if configured incorrectly or used on the wrong workload: write heavy workloads do not perform well with LTCS.  Try testing a new compaction strategy on a [single node](http://blog.alteroot.org/articles/2015-04-20/change-cassandra-compaction-strategy-on-production-cluster.html) and review the performance metrics to validate the strategy will meet performance expectations.